# Merge the same dates

Tags: r

I have data in this format

```
data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), 
           date = c("2008-08-04 05:45:07","2008-08-04 09:45:07","2008-08-04 05:45:07"), 
           text = c("stg","another","final"))
#   id                date    text
# 1  1 2008-08-04 05:45:07     stg
# 2  1 2008-08-04 09:45:07 another
# 3  2 2008-08-04 05:45:07   final
```

How is it possible to merge the rows with the same date into one for the same id. Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), 
           date = c("2008-08-04", "2008-08-04"), 
           text = c("stg another","final"))
#   id       date        text
# 1  1 2008-08-04 stg another
# 2  2 2008-08-04       final
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `aggregate` like below

```
dfout <- aggregate(text ~ date + id, df, paste)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  id                date       text
1  1 2008-08-04 05:45:07 stg, final
2  2 2008-08-04 09:45:07    another
```

Comment: is there any option to use sep = " " instead of comma?

Comment: @Nathalie you can try `aggregate(text ~ date, df, paste, sep = "")` or `aggregate(text ~ date, df, paste, collapse = "")`

Comment: @Nathalie if you want to keep dates without hours, minutes or seconds, you can append the following line to the end of above solution: `dfout$date <- format(as.Date(dfout$date),"%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: why the solution doesn't keep the id?

Comment: @Nathalie sorry I was not aware of it. Please see my updates